# asyncore.dispatcher in python: when are the handle_closed and handle_read executed?

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

There are two files: server.py and client.py, both written with the help of asyncore.dispatcher

***Server.py***

```
import asyncore, socket

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind(('', port))
        self.listen(1)
        print "Waiting for connection..."

    def handle_accept(self):
        socket, address = self.accept()
        print 'Connection by', address
        socket.send("Hello Server")

    def handle_read(self):
        print "Reading..."
        out_buffer = self.recv(1024)
        if not out_buffer:
            self.close()
        print out_buffer

    def handle_closed(self):
        print "Server: Connection Closed"
        self.close()

s = Server('0.0.0.0', 5007)
asyncore.loop()
```

***Client.py***

```
import asyncore, socket

class Client(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))
        print "Client Start..."

    def handle_close(self):
        print "Client: Connection Closed"
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print "Received ", data
        self.send("Hello Client")

c = Client('127.0.0.1', 5007)
asyncore.loop()
```

***Result:***

Execute `server.py`:

```
Waiting for connection...
```

then `client.py`:

```
Client Start...
Received  Hello Server
Client: Connection Closed
Client: Connection Closed
```

Finally the client.py exited, and there is one more line displayed in the ouput window of server.py and the server keeps running:

```
Connection by ('127.0.0.1', 58197)
```

There are something that I cannot understand:

1. Why is the function `handle_closed` in ***client.py*** executed twice?
2. Why isn't the function `handle_reading` in ***server.py*** executed? The ***client.py*** has sent message("Hello Client"), but why cannot the server receive it?
3. Why isn't the function `handle_closed` in ***server.py*** executed? I want to execute some codes in ***server.py*** when the client exits, but it seems that it does nothing to do `handle_closed` in ***server.py***?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Asyncore talk

The `handle_read()` in server.py will never be called.

*But why?! It's a server class...*

Yes, but `Server` class uses its socket for **listening** any non-established connections. Any reads on it go to `handle_accept()`, where actual channel sockets (connected to some endpoint) should be given to new instance of some `dispatcher`-inherited class (preferably). In your `Server`'s `handle_accept()` method sockets got by `accept()` were local and thus deleted upon exiting this function, so: new connection was accepted, text was sent and after that socket was immediately killed.

Have some read on asyncore module and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18026873/2643692) in other question.

#### Server

You need to, like I said, make new class for connections in server.py:

```
class ClientHandler(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            return
        print "Received:", data

    def handle_close(self):
        print "Server: Connection Closed"
        self.close()
```

Note here that reading don't need to manually close socket when null is recieved - `asyncore` takes care of properly closing connection.

Then you have to instantiate it in `Server` when connection is made:

```
    def handle_accept(self):
        ...
        ClientHandler(socket)
```

You also made spelling mistake in `Server` - method's proper name is `handle_close`. Though it wouldn't be useful. Everything client-connection related is in `ClientHandler`.

#### Client

In client.py you just need to modify `handle_read()`:

```
    if data:
        print "Received ", data
```

Change to:

```
    if not data:
        return
    print "Received ", data
```

Why? Without this `send()` would be called even when socket is actually closed, resulting in `handle_close()` being called for second time, by `asyncore`. Like I said - `asyncore` takes care of this.

### Notes

Now you can write more complex server-side class for connections. You could also learn how OS-level sockets work, so you won't get into trouble.

`asyncore` itself is a pretty nice wrapper for sockets, but if you want to do higher-lever things, like HTTP or SMTP processing in some event-driven environment, then [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) library would interest you!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue today. The handle_close class runs twice because the read function is returning a set of blank data that then causes the handle_write to trigger, when the handle_write sees the blank data, it closes the request a second time.

As stated above, you need to seperate the handle_read and handle_write functions into a seperate 'handler' class. Then, just check the buffer for blank data, if the data is blank just return.

In the code below, I am adding the length to beggining of each request. So, I pull that first in order to get the buffer size. If its blank, The function just returns

```
class Handler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
  def __init__(self, conn_sock, client_address, server):
    self.SERVER = server
    self.CA = client_address
    self.DATA = ''
    self.out_buffer = ''
    self.BUFFER = 1024
    self.is_writable = False
    # Create with an already provided socket
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, conn_sock)

  def readable(self):
    return True

  def writable(self):
    return self.is_writable

  def handle_read(self):
    buffer = str(self.recv(8))
    if buffer != '': size = int(buffer)
    else: return
    data = self.recv(size)
    if data:
        self.DATA += data
        self.is_writable = True

  def handle_write(self):
    if self.DATA:
        self.RESPONSE = processRequest(self.DATA)
        dlen = "%08d" % (len(self.RESPONSE)+8,)
        sent = self.sendall(dlen+self.RESPONSE)
        self.DATA = self.RESPONSE[sent:]
        self.RESPONSE = ''
    if len(self.DATA) == 0:
        self.is_writable = False

  def handle_close(self):
    self.close()


class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):
  FAMILY = socket.AF_INET
  TYPE = socket.SOCK_STREAM

  def __init__(self):
    self.HANDLER = Handler
    #check for a specified host
    self.HOST =  "localhost"
    #check for a specified port
    self.PORT = 50007
    #check the queue size
    self.QUEUE = 5
    #set the reuse var
    self.REUSE = False
    #dispatch
    self.dispatch()

  def dispatch(self):
    #init the dispatcher
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(self.FAMILY, self.TYPE)
    #check for address reuse
    if self.REUSE: self.set_reuse_addr()
    #bind and activate the server
    self.server_bind()
    self.server_activate()

  def server_bind(self):
    self.bind((self.HOST, self.PORT))

  def server_activate(self):
    self.listen(self.QUEUE)

  def fileno(self):
    return self.socket.fileno()

  def serve(self):
    asyncore.loop()

  def handle_accept(self):
    (conn_sock, client_address) = self.accept()
    if self.verify_request(conn_sock, client_address):
        self.process_request(conn_sock, client_address)

  def verify_request(self, conn_sock, client_address):
    return True

  def process_request(self, conn_sock, client_address):
    self.HANDLER(conn_sock, client_address, self.LOG, self.LOGFILE, self)

  def handle_close(self):
    self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
    server.serve()
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the `handle_read()` work , you SHOULD define the `readable()` function . This function must return either `True` or `False` . I think adding this function to your code will fix the problem :

```
def readable(self):
    return True
```

for some examples and more details visit this link: https://parijatmishra.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/writing-a-server-with-pythons-asyncore-module/